# Issue With Google Cloud Platform GUI Flickering

Tags: google-chrome, display, cloud, google-cloud-platform, screen-tearing

Ok, this is bizarre and I'm not sure if I'm in the right place or not so sorry in advance.
when I access the Google Cloud platform the Console GUI..

the page starts flickering:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKHxZ.png)

I don't know why, when I change to other tabs it's ok.
it made me believe in the beginning maybe my screen had an issue? which scared me.

so I checked a different one everything is fine as soon as I visit the same website (only this, not the SSH or other places related to the google cloud platform) the same thing happened closed taps, restart PC..etc

let the PC rest and come back again, nothing.

it's really annoying when trying to click on something from the drop-down menu!